# Routing Error Try running rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, devise, controller

I got 2 diferents message but whit the same error, Im using a devise for users... Here is my routes.rb

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "static_pages#home"
match '/contact', :to=>'static_pages#contact'
match '/about', :to=>'static_pages#about'
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

whit my routes.rb just like that i got the next error

```
uninitialized constant UsersController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

but if a remove the "resourses: users" i got the following error

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/27"
```

I put my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
     @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to user_session_path
    else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
end

end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #redirect_to @user
end
end
```

Comment: What is file name of `UsersController` and what is the full path to it?

Comment: user_controller... and the the path is current_user (i don't know where is it)

Comment: Oh well. File should be named `users_controller.rb`, not `user_controller.rb`

Comment: And if the file name is `user_controller`, then that is wrong. It should have the file extenision `.rb` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename for your users model must be `users_controller.rb` and be in the controllers folder.